# Apple Pushnotification Issue

Tags: php, ios, iphone, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am new for apple push notification. I am currently working on ios app with chat funcationality. For this app, web-services are built in PHP.

There is a functionality, when user send a chat message to another user that time we send a push notification through PHP that web-service to message receiver user.
Notification working fine that I have checked.

Now issue is, sometimes push notification works fine but sometime its not. 
So I want to know when ios push notification fails to send.

I have put write to log and log shows notification sent successfully.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the Feedback service to get information about failed push notifications via APN:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH101-SW3

Looks like the link doesn't anchor to the section - so you will need to search for the entry 
:( sry.

Hope that helps